# Split string around spaces without colons in between

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, regex-lookarounds

I have a problem where I have to split strings if there is **more than one space** between two strings. But the condition is, that series of spaces should not follow a colon(:) or preceeds it (like in case (C) and (D)).  Follwing is the regex i am using:

```
    str_ = re.split(r'(.+?)(?!<\:)(\s\s+)(?!\:)(.+)',text),
```

where text can be any of following examples type:
e.g:

```
    foo1:bar1   foo2:bar2      (A)#O/P should be [foo1:bar1,foo2:bar2]
    foo1:bar1                  (B)#O/P should be [foo1:bar1]
    foo1    :bar1   foo2:bar2  (C)#O/P should be [foo1    :bar1,foo2:bar2]
    foo1    :bar1              (D)#O/P should be [foo1    :bar1]
```

For example (C) and (D), I am getting split whereas there should not be. Please help.

Comment: Try `r'\s{2,}(?![\s:])'`. It seems checking for `:` on the right side is enough for your data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
re.split(r'(?<![\s:])\s{2,}(?![\s:])', s)
```

**Details**

- `(?<![\s:])` - no whitespace or `:` is allowed immediately to the left of the current location
- `\s{2,}` - two or more whitespaces (a shorter variant of `\s\s+`)
- `(?![\s:])` -  no whitespace or `:` is allowed immediately to the right of the current location.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6UL7Sg/1) (`\s` is replace with space for demo purposes).

[Python demo](https://ideone.com/1iU6MF):

```
import re
strs = ['foo1:bar1   foo2:bar2', 'foo1:bar1', 'foo1    :bar1   foo2:bar2', 'foo1    :bar1', 'f   :fdfd   f:f', 'f:   fdfd   f:f']
for s in strs:
    print(re.split(r'(?<![\s:])\s{2,}(?![\s:])', s))
```

Output:

```
['foo1:bar1', 'foo2:bar2']
['foo1:bar1']
['foo1    :bar1', 'foo2:bar2']
['foo1    :bar1']
['f   :fdfd', 'f:f']
['f:   fdfd', 'f:f']
```

Answer (score 1):

I recommend just using `re.findall` here:

```
input = "foo1    :bar1   foo2:bar2"
result = re.findall(r'\S+\s*:\s*\S+', input)
print(result)

['foo1    :bar1', 'foo2:bar2']
```

The simplified regex pattern matches:

```
\S+  one or more non whitespace characters
\s*  which are followed by optional whitespace
:    followed by a colon and
\s*  more optional whitespace
\S+ one or more non whitespace characters
```

Comment: its not handling case `foo1          :            bar1`, (spaces on both sides) though adding `\s*` after colon might solve it.

Comment: @AdityaGupta Thanks for the correction.  As a tip, if you find yourself doing a complicated regex split, consider using a regex iteration instead.  Sometimes it lets you get away with a much simpler pattern.

Comment: Yes, you are right @Tim. Your solution seems simple and clean.